# Yii2 Disable user registration for amnah/yii2-user

Tags: yii2

I am using the user module [amnah/yii2-user](https://github.com/amnah/yii2-user) in my Yii2 application. I need to disable some actions for the user module.

For example, how can I disable the user registration (/user/register).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The User module you are using, unfortunately, does not have any option to disable the user registration via configuration like `dektrium/yii2-user`.

You'll need to create a controller and extend the [**`DefaultController.php`**](https://github.com/amnah/yii2-user/blob/master/controllers/DefaultController.php), and override the action like below.

```
<?php

namespace app\controllers;
use amnah\yii2\user\controllers\DefaultController as BaseDefault;

class DefaultController extends BaseDefault{
    public function actionRegister()
    {
        return $this->redirect(["/user/login"]);
    }
}
```

don't forget to map your controller first for overriding the action

```
'modules' => [
    'user' => [
        'class' => 'app\modules\MyModule',
        'controllerMap' => [
            'default' => 'app\controllers\DefaultController',
        ],
    ],
],
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to **@Muhammad** answer - replacing single controller may work in some simple cases, but usually the only sane way of dealing with such cases (removing core feature from big module) is to fork package and do necessary changes directly in its source code.

Even if you override register action and redirect to login page, you still may have multiple confusing "click here to register" links in your application. And updating package may break your workaround and making registration possible (for example by changing action name or introducing different way of registration).

---

The best solution would be contributing to module package and adding setting to disable registration. Then your use case will be officially supported - no risk that upgrade will add this feature again, and you will not waste time on maintaining your fork.

Comment: hey rob feel free to edit the answer and add the info if it can improve the answer.

Comment: I decided to add it as a separate answer, since it is completely different approach.

Comment: yeah i understand, thumbsup